# Gradle Dependecies Command cant find other maven repos

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, gradlew

I want to check my projects dependencies but having problem when running

> ./gradlew app:dependencies

Here is the result of terminal.

[image: Terminal Result]

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `build.gradle` file, preferably as text, rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: You forget to add new repository to build.gradle. See https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for suggestions, i tried but had hard times with alignments. Its requires some fixing sometimes when copy & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add new google repo to root gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
}
```